# SQL Server 2008 Registration with Product Key

Tags: sql-server-2008, product-key

A colleague of mine gave me the SQL Server 2008 Standard ISO image and I used that while building a Virtual Machine.

Now, when I installed SQL Server with that above mentioned ISO, I did not give it a key and I chose Enterprise Evaluation.

So, the instance has now been activated with 180-day expiration.

I do have a valid MSDN Subscriber login but when I login and search for SQL Server 2008 it comes up with the download but says No Product Key is required.

How do I now enter the product key?

Comment: Microsoft doesn't sell the 2008 version anymore. You'll have to purchase and install the 2012 version or buy a product key from some retailer (not sure if that's possible).

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks, but I have a valid MSDN Subscriber Login and if I were to login to MSDN and download the 3.1GB file, and use that for installation, it would work without the 180 day expiration. Basically, I am a legit MSDN Ultimate Subscriber, how can I ensure that the 180 day expiration goes away?

Comment: When it comes to licensing of software, your best bet is to contact the producer itself: [Contact Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/). That way, you get *promised* it will work (and a refund if it doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

The msdn installation package has the key embedded (pre-pidded). In the installation programm, you can choose if you want to install an evaluation version (as you did), or if you want to install the full version.

If you choose the installation of the non-evaluation version, the key is already filled in. You only have to click "ok" and proceed with the installation.